# How do I bin data based on weight of evidence bins from the "Information" package in R

Tags: r, binning

The following lines of code in R

```
library("Information")

set.seed(100)

Y <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=50)
X <- dnorm(rnorm(50))

data <- as.data.frame(cbind(X,Y))

create_infotables(data, y = "Y", bins = 5)
```

Generate output:

```
$Tables
$Tables$X
            X  N Percent        WOE         IV
1 [0.01,0.09]  9    0.18 -0.3834862 0.02655379
2  [0.1,0.23] 10    0.20  0.2451225 0.03839546
3 [0.25,0.36] 10    0.20 -0.5658078 0.10217411
4 [0.36,0.39] 10    0.20  0.2451225 0.11401578
5  [0.39,0.4] 11    0.22  0.3992731 0.14809223


$Summary
  Variable        IV
1        X 0.1480922

attr(,"class")
[1] "Information"
```

Now what I want to achieve is to transform column X of the data frame to a column containing the WOE value of the bin corresponding to the data point. So observations in the data frame with X values in the interval [0.01,0.09] should all be replaced with value -0.3834862, and so on.

How do I proceed?

with `cut()` I got a little closer:

```
> cut(X, c(0,01.09,0.23,0.36,0.39,0.4),
      labels = c(-0.3834862,0.2451225,-0.5658078,0.2451225,0.3992731))

 [1] -0.5658078 0.2451225  -0.5658078 -0.3834862 -0.5658078 0.2451225  -0.3834862 0.2451225  0.2451225  0.2451225 
[11] -0.5658078 0.2451225  -0.5658078 -0.3834862 0.2451225  0.2451225  -0.3834862 -0.3834862 0.2451225  0.2451225 
[21] -0.3834862 -0.5658078 -0.3834862 0.2451225  -0.3834862 -0.5658078 -0.3834862 0.2451225  -0.3834862 -0.3834862
[31] 0.2451225  -0.3834862 -0.3834862 -0.3834862 0.2451225  -0.5658078 0.2451225  -0.5658078 -0.3834862 0.2451225 
[41] 0.2451225  0.2451225  0.2451225  0.2451225  0.2451225  -0.5658078 -0.3834862 -0.3834862 -0.3834862 -0.3834862
Levels: -0.3834862 0.2451225 -0.5658078 0.2451225 0.3992731
Warning message:
In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
  duplicated levels in factors are deprecated
```

However the values in the result are the factor labels. `as.numeric()` does not help because it returns the label numbers. Another problem with `cut()` is that I do not know how to extract cut points from $Tables$X$X and pass them to the cut function.

Comment: the function `cut` can transform X to a nominal variable which you can use to assign the values you want.

Comment: I got a little closer using cut:

Comment: Sounds like you want to store and use the breaks created from `create_infotables()`, then use them in `cut()`. If you want the vector of integer levels instead of the labels, use `cut(..., labels=F)`.

Answer (score 0):

> However the values in the result are the factor labels. `as.numeric()` does not help because it returns the label numbers.

What did you expect? Normally, `cut()` gives you a factor output, whose (string) labels contain the breaks.

**If you only want to get the integer vector of level codes, not the (string) labels, do [`cut(, ...labels=FALSE)`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cut.html)**

But apparently you don't want either (then what do you want?).

> Another problem with cut() is that I do not know how to extract cut points from $Tables$X$X and pass them to the cut function.

You want to get the vector of breaks from `create_infotables()`:

- Store the output: `mytbl <- create_infotables(data, y = "Y", bins = 5)`
- Then figure out what attribute of `mytbl` to access to get your custom breaks. Look at `ls(mytbl)` or `attributes(mytbl)`. Say it's `mytbl$mybreaks` (I don't know that package but you get the idea).
- Then use your custom breaks `cut(mytbl, breaks=mytbl$mybreaks)`